# Show that there is no neighborhood of $0$ such that the function $f(x)=x \left[1+\sin^2 \frac{1}{x}\right]$ is increasing

Tags: analysis, functions, derivatives, solution-verification

Problem: show that there is no neighborhood of $0$ such that the function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x\left[1+\sin^2 \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right], \ \text{if} \ x \ne 0, \\ 0, \ \text{if} \ x=0 \end{cases}$$
is increasing.

My attempt: let $r>0$ and let $I_r:=(-r,r)\setminus \{0\}$, for any $x \in I_r$ the function $f$ is differentiable (because it is sum, product and composition of differentiable functions for $x\ne0$) and for $x \in I_r$ it is
$$f'(x)=1+\sin^2 \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\frac{2}{x} \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
Notice that $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f'(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^-} f'(x)$ don't exist: it is enough to consider the sequences $a_n=\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+2n\pi\right)^{-1}$ and $b_n=\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}+2n\pi\right)^{-1}$, with $a_n \to 0$ and $b_n \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ to observe that $f'(a_n)$ and $f'(b_n)$ tends to $\infty$ or $-\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ (a similar reasoning works for $x \to 0^-$ too).

This means that in $I_r$ the sign of $f'$ changes infinitely many times, so it can't be $f'(x)>0$ for any $x \in I_r$ and hence $f$ can't be increasing in $I_r$. Since $r>0$ is arbitrary, this holds for any $r>0$ and so it holds for any neighborhood of $0$.

Is this correct? If yes, is there a more rigorous way to say that $f'$ changes sign infinitely many times in $I_r$?

Comment: I think you did a good work and it's enough rigorous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like what you did. The argument could be more straightforward though.

The sentence

> Notice that $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f'(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^-} f'(x)$ don't exist

doesn't support the result to be proved as those limits may not exist while $f^\prime$ may always be positive in a neighborhood of zero.

The only important thing is to get a sequence $\{c_n\}$ converging to zero such that $f^\prime(c_n) \lt 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. And this is what you have for the sequence $\{b_n\}$ you mention.